# Java FX liveconnect - calling javascript function from FX application

Tags: java, javascript, applet, javafx-2, liveconnect

I am facing a problem, I need to communicate from Java FX application to browser. Prior to that I found info as:

```
var jsObject = netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow(applet);
jsObject.call("show_alert", []);
```

With this I can access JavaScript function. But my Java FX application is not an applet (not implementing `JApplet`). 
So what could I give as input to getWindow().

Any Suggestion?

Comment: i am trying thid with the reference of https://blogs.oracle.com/rakeshmenonp/entry/javafx_javascript

Comment: How are you running this application?  Is it embedded in a web page?  If not, you have no chance of accessing JS in the browser.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Ya i am accessing in web page only.

Comment: What @AndrewThompson asking is are you accessing the JavaScript through an embedded WebView inside your JavaFX application or your JavaFX application is running as a webstart/browser?

In the first case you can, the later one you cannot.

Comment: @ francisOpt In the webStart, i need to access through browser (applet).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments it is unclear if you're JavaFX code is running embedded within a web browser page (in other words an applet) or it is some other configuration.  However, you should start by using the following.

```
JSObject jsWin = getHostServices().getWebContext();
if (jsWin != null) {
    jsWin.eval("show_alert();");
}
```

If this doesn't work then please comment with what's not working and what the specific run-time configuration is.

`getHostServices()` is a method on a JavaFX `Application` as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html).